# Delegation a set of tasks to another host that relies on conditional

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My question is slightly complex. I have some multi-node cluster infrastructure that orchestrated with Ansible.

And there can be nodes that Kubernetes masters or slaves. Depending on that I need to delegate a specific set of tasks to master node if current task is playing on slave node.

For example, I have inventory structure like this:

```
[k8s_master]
hostname ansible_ssh_host= ... etc.

[k8s_slaves]
hostname ansible_ssh_host= ... etc.

[k8s_cluster:children]
k8s_master
k8s_slaves
```

I have a task that checking if k8s node is master or slave and registering some value:

```
    - name: Checking if node is kubernetes master
      stat:
        path: "{{kubeconf}}"
      register: master_conf
```

and I want to execute some set of tasks depending on master_conf.stat.exists value (true or false) locally (if the node is k8s master) or delegate it to master (if the node is k8s slave). Problems:

- I need to delegate a set of tasks or dynamically included
         playbook but delegate_to does not work with `block:` or
         `include_tasks:`.
- I need to delegate this set of tasks depending
     on conditional statement or play it locally.
- I need to pass node
     hostname to this set of tasks even it they will be playing on remote
     node. For example, I can set it like that:

```
         set_fact:
           node_hostname: "{{ansible_hostname}}"
```

and then I need the variable `{{node_hostname}}` inside tasks even if they were
   delegated. Then I need to register some variables during the play on
   master node and use it in tasks on the slave node again.

Still can't find right solution. I've tried something like:

```
    - name: Including tasks to perform if we are on the master node
      include_tasks: set-of-tasks.yml
      when: master_conf.stat.exists

    - name: Including tasks to perform if we are on the slave node
      include_tasks: set-of-tasks.yml
      delegate_to: "{{item}}"
      delegate_facts: true
      with_items: "{{groups.k8s_master}}"
      when: master_conf.stat.exists == false
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: When you run the loop `with_items: "{{groups.k8s_master}}"` these hosts are masters. Right? Why do you need to test it? `when: master_conf.stat.exists == false`.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I need to run this loop in playbook after checking that current node is a slave. So there are two options, I have recently update example in post. If original node is master then set-of-tasks must be played on the same node but if it is slave then set-of-tasks is delegated. But this won't work in any case because Ansible can't combine `include_tasks` with `delegate_to`:
`FAILED! => {"reason": "'delegate_to' is not a valid attribute for a TaskInclude\n`

Comment: Ansible also doesn't support looping over block (as I can see) so I can't delegate this set of tasks as a block too.
`FAILED! => {"reason": "'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Block\n`

Comment: Why are you testing you are on a master/slave since this info is available from your inventory (e.g. `inventory_hostname in groups['k8s_master']`) ? ansible supports looping for `include_tasks` and can accept arbitrary vars your can reuse in your included file, including in a `delegate_to` clause with the `default(omit)` filter if necessary. For what its worth, it looks to me you just need to separate your tasks in different plays targeted against the correct groups of hosts.

Comment: @Zeitounator well it's even more complex actually. This task deploys sandbox enviroment (for behavioral analysis) to the k8s nodes. And it targeted against so-called `sandbox_nodes` group where can be both k8s masters or k8s slaves. So I have to check if it's master during the play and dynamically delegate my tasks to master node if it's slave (because there is no apiservers on slaves).

Comment: You can target your play to the intersection of two groups with the corresponding [pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns) e.g. `hosts: sandbox_nodes:&k8s_slaves`. If you still need to do this for a specific task, you just have to check that the current node is in the corresponding group as I proposed earlier (e.g. `when: inventory_hostname in groups['k8s_slaves']`).

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks, last remark about using when statement can be useful because it'll  either do the job in most cases without checking k8s config file.

Answer (score -2):

Resolved this case with combination of `include` and arbitrary var containing hostname of the node where I need to delegate my task (`include_task` doesn't support arbitrary vars).
So the syntax is:

```
    - name: Checking if node is kubernetes master
      stat:
        path: "{{kubeconf}}"
      register: master_conf

    - name: Including tasks to perform if we are on the master node
      include: set-of-tasks.yml
      when: master_conf.stat.exists

    - name: Including tasks to perform if we are on the slave node
      include: set-of-tasks.yml
      delegate_host: "{{item}}"
      with_items: "{{groups.k8s_master}}"
      when: master_conf.stat.exists == false
```

And then in set-of-tasks.yml adding `delegate_to` to delegated tasks:
delegate_to: "{{delegate_host}}"

For some reason `default(omit)` doesn't work for me (Ansible tries to resolve original node hostname and fails though it works fine with that name from inventory file with IP specified). So I added something like that at the beginning of set-of-tasks.yml:

```
    - name: Setting target kubernetes master node
      set_fact:
        delegate_host: "{{ansible_hostname}}"
      when: delegate_host is undefined
```

Comment: `include` is deprecated soon, you may want to use `import_tasks`

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen Given the original `include` in OP the correct equivalent is rather `include_tasks`

Comment: `include_task doesn't support arbitrary vars` <= can you please specify how you came to this conclusion? Because it is actually entirely false.